# Ghidra API: Getting the parameter storage locations given a FunctionSignature

Tags: ghidra, api, plugin

I want to create a tool that help analyzing certain code. One feature is analyzing calls that are made through a global function pointer. The first parameter is usually a constant pointer, which I want to retrieve the value of. While I could just hard-code the register this parameter is passed in, I would like to get used to the Ghidra API sufficiently to have it tell me which register it is.

So this is what I already have: I look up the global function pointer using `ptr = program.getSymbols("gImportantFunctionPointer").next()`, then I retrieve the signature using `sig = (FunctionSignature)((Pointer)l.getDataAt(ptr.getAddress()).getDataType()).getDataType();`. I do unterstand that the `FunctionSignature` object is processor independent and thus can't determine the register allocation. I already tried to create a `FunctionPrototype` object, as it has a promising constructor accepting a `CompilerSpec` and a `FunctionSignature`, which feels like exactly what you need to determine parameter storage, but if that `FunctionPrototype` is "backed by FunctionSignature", the method `getParam(idx)` just returns `null`.

As I am dealing with a function pointer, I am looking for ways not involving accessing any actual functions stored in the binary. While of course there is a "default implementation" I could use as reference, I'd rather learn a way that can get directly from the signature to the parameter locations without requiring to find an actual function that has the same type. It must be possible in *some* way, because the decompiler is able to decompile invocations of any function pointer, but I didn't yet find any convenient way (and I don't even know whether there is) in the Ghidra API.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no ready-made function to solve the question, but looking at [the implemenation of the function editor](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/317a8814883804f0c4f18c64d97411b1c6d6283e/Ghidra/Features/Base/src/main/java/ghidra/app/plugin/core/function/editor/FunctionEditorModel.java#L614) points out the way how to do it. I wrote this utilitiy function to get the parameter and return locations for a given function prototype:

```java
import ghidra.program.model.data.DataType;
import ghidra.program.model.listing.FunctionSignature;
import ghidra.program.model.listing.Program;
import ghidra.program.model.listing.VariableStorage;

class Utilities
{
    public static DataType[] getTypeList(FunctionSignature sig)
    {
        DataType[] types = new DataType[sig.getArguments().length + 1];
        types[0] = sig.getReturnType();
        for (int i = 0; i < sig.getArguments().length; i++)
            types[i + 1] = sig.getArguments()[i].getDataType();
        return types;
    }

    public static VariableStorage[] getStorageLocations(
            Program program,
            FunctionSignature sig,
            boolean include_auto)
    {
        return program.getCompilerSpec()
                      .getCallingConvention(sig.getCallingConventionName())
                      .getStorageLocations(program,
                                           getTypeList(sig),
                                           include_auto);
    }

}
```

The key point is the method `getStorageLocations` on the `PrototypeModel` interface. The first element of the array returned describes the return value - all other elements the parameters.